# Manipulating DropDownList within TemplateField

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu, templatefield

I have a dropdownlist inside of a TemplateField, within a GridView.

I would like to dynamically add list items to it and write code to handle when the index changes. How do I go about manipulating the list, since I can't directly reference the DropDownList when it's in a TemplateField.

Here is my code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Transfer Location" Visible="false">
   <EditItemTemplate>
      <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTransferLocation" runat="server" ></asp:DropDownList>
   </EditItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Why can't you directly reference the DropDown? myGrid.Rows[index].FindControl("ddlTransferLocation") as DropDownList. index can be found from the GridView.SelectedIndex if you're using that. Also some of the per-row GridView EventArgs expose the row the event was fired from (e.RowIndex where e is GridView*EventArgs)

Comment: Also, you want to "write code to handle when the index changes". Which index do you mean, the GridView or each DropDownList?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you want to do correctly, you can handle adding items to your drop down like this:

```
foreach (GridViewRow currentRow in gvMyGrid.Rows)
{
    DropDownList myDropDown = (currentRow.FindControl("ddlTransferLocation") as DropDownList);
    if (myDropDown != null)
    {
        myDropDown.Items.Add(new ListItem("some text", "a value"));
    }
}
```

Then, if you mean handling the index change of the DropDownList you just need to add an event handler to your control:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTransferLocation" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlTransferLocation_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Then in that event handler you can use `(sender as DropDownList)` to get whatever you need from it:

```
protected void ddlTransferLocation_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList myDropDown = (sender as DropDownList);
    if (myDropDown != null) // do something
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, thank you! One additional question though, my method makes a template field visible when you change to a specific dropdownfield. However it resets the dropdown selected index back to 0. Is there any way to have it not reset the selected index?

Comment: The problem is the dynamically added stuff isn't being persisted in ViewState or ControlState. The real correct way to handle that is write a custom control that extends the GridView to handle that added state issue. I'm working on a quick fix type solution for you

Comment: This one is actually pretty nasty because of the state thing. There isn't a quick and easy solution. Do you need it to do anything server side or could you just use some jQuery to add the dropdown items and the toggle visibility of your other field based on the dropdown selection? It would probably be a lot easier (and actually a better user experience) if that could get what you needed.

Comment: I wouldn't be opposed to client side programming if it's easier. I've never really mixed javascript and ASP.NET before though.